# PyroCMS 2.2 Logo Not Displaying

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm using PyroCMS 2.2 for a new site and the Bootstrap 3 theme.  Unfortunately, the theme does not include a placeholder for a header logo.  So, I browsed the docs and Slack feed.  I found example syntax as follows:

```
{{ theme:image_url file="mylogo.jpg" }}
```

However, when I save the header partial and view my [site](http://iaqfp.org), instead of the logo image displaying, the path to the image file itself is shown.  How should I structure the code so that the image is loaded instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{{ theme:image file="mylogo.jpg" }}` instead of `theme:image_url` - for obvious reasons :)

And check the docs for more information on the different plugin functions: http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/plugins/theme